# the index in representation theory

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I'm studying quantum field theory.
In my text book, generators of compact groups are normalized by $\rm{Tr}$$(T^aT^b)=\frac{1}{2}\delta^{ab}$.
However, the index $T(R)$ is defined by $\mathrm{Tr}
$$(T^a_RT^b_R)=T(R)\delta^{ab}$, where the $R$ is the label of representations and the $T^a_R$ is a representation matrix.
This definition seems inconsistent with normalization of generators unless $T(R)=\frac{1}{2}$ in any representations.
Whats happened?

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems to me that the normalization takes place inside either the matrix group itself or in the adjoint rep (the latter being a more generic choice). The images of the generators in the representation space are not constrained by that normalization. In short, $T^a$ and $T_R^a$ are different matrices. The former being a special case of the latter (some "natural" representation is set aside for the purposes of normalization). IIRC a similar thing is done with Casimir elements.

Comment: I don't understand the notations, but I can see no inconsistency. Generators are normalised one way, and an index is defined another way, where's the conflict?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen $T^a$ is not a matrix but a operator.Can I think the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ is the normalization of operators and $T(R)$ is the normalization of matrices, so the two normalization factors is chosen independently since  representations, which are maps from operators to matrices, just have to keep the algebras of generators?

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen I thought $\mathrm{Tr}$$(T^aT^b)=\frac{1}{2}\delta^{ab}$ must be true in any representations. Because I have not chosen a representation yet. Can I normalize again or independently after fixing a representation?

Comment: How do you define the trace of an operator without reference to the space the operator is acting on, i.e. without turning it into a matrix? Anyway, the representation must respect the relations between the normalized generators, and this forces their traces to change according to the space they act on. For a simple example, let the the operator $x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ act on the span of $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^n\}$ and see its trace change as $n$ grows.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Sorry, I misunderstood. $T^a$ is a matrix. Please see the text(http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf). In eq.(69.8) in p.408, generator matrices is normalized with factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ generally. It is also used in eq.(70.6) in p.413. But in eq.(70.9) the normalization factor is replaced by $T(R)$. I must forget the first normalization condition after eq.(70.9)?

Comment: Having a representation means that there is a homomorphism (of Lie algebras or Lie groups, I don't have the time to check which) sending $T^a$ to $T_R^a$. The images $T_R^a$ must satisfy the same relations (in the case of Lie algebras these would be commutator relations) as the original $T^a$:s. But their traces may be very different. The traces certainly vary from one representation to another.

Comment: The point that you may be missing is that the normalization simply seeks to specify fixed elements of the original algebra/group. Their images under representation live in a different space. For example $SU(N)$ has an $N(N-1)/2$ dimensional representation (the second wedge power of the defining representation). This gives us a group homomorphism $f:SU(N)\to SU(N(N-1)/2)$. Here $T_R^a=f(T^a)$ (replace $f$ with its effect on the tangent vectors, if it is about Lie algebras). IOW we no longer need to define $T_R^a$:s, only the $T^a:$s in the defining representation (here $SU(N)$).

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why the index should be the same in all representations. The equations you quote merely imply that $T(D)=\frac12$, where $D$ is the defining representation to which the generators $T^a$ belong.

Comment: You mean the equation $\rm{Tr}$$(T^aT^a)=\frac{1}{2}\delta^{ab}$ maybe only valid in the defining representation in this text? But under eq.(70.10), it is described the SO(N) is not the case.

Comment: @user59608: No, that's not what I mean. First, there's a typo there; it should be $\operatorname{Tr}(T^aT^b)$. Further, that sentence makes no sense, since the $T^a$ are by definition the matrices in the defining representation, so it's unclear what it would mean for this equation to be valid in another representation.

Comment: @user59608: About $SO(N)$: This is a new point you raise that wasn't in the question. My interpretation of the text would be that $(69.8)$ is introduced explicitly for $SU(N)$ (see the bottom of page $407$); $(70.6)$ then appears to be used more generally, but without actually making use of the factor (since it's only used to show that something is zero). So I'd count this as an oversight and regard $(69.8)$ as defining only the standard normalization for $SU(N)$, and not the standard normalization for $SO(N)$ that the text underneath $(70.10)$ refers to.

Comment: $T^a$ implies the defining representation? Then (70.6) can be replaced by $\mathrm{Tr}$$(T^aT^b)\propto\delta^{ab}$?

Comment: @user59608: Sorry, it seems we're talking past each other; I can never really make any sense of your questions. I'm not sure what you mean by "implies" here. The $T^a$ are introduced even before the concept of representations and thus cannot refer to anything other than the defining representation. This is reemphasized on p. $412$ underneath equation $(70.1)$. So the use of the notation $T^a$ implies a reference to the defining representation; perhaps this is what you meant?

Comment: @user59608: On your second question, I don't understand why you write "Then". Equation $(70.6)$ clearly implies (not: can be replaced by) the proportionality you write, but that has nothing to do with what the $T^a$ denote; it's merely due to the definition of the proportionality symbol $\propto$.

Comment: I thought the $T^a$ are introduced even before the concept of representations and thus "can" refer to anything other than the defining representation. So I thought $\mathrm{Ta}$$(T^aT^b)=\frac{1}{2}\delta^{ab}$ is valid in any representations. Is this mistake?

Comment: @user59608: As far as I can tell the entire text consistently speaks against that interpretation: page $408$ first paragraph (properties of "generator matrices $T^a$" being inferred from special unitarity), third paragraph ($T^a=\frac12\sigma^a$ for $SU(2)$), page $410$ last paragraph and page $412$ first paragraph (contrast between $T_R^a$ and "the original generator matrices $T^a$), page $413$ ("the $T^a$'s are the original generator matrices"). I don't see a single formulation that supports your interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

You evidently misread Srednicki's text--he always works with specific irreps. The index 1/2 is for the defining representation, strictly and uniquely. This is a carryover of the convention which started with flavor *SU(3)* which paid special attention to its isospin *SU(2)* subgroup and assigned the index 1/2 to all *SU(N)* s. Again for  *SU(N)* s, the index of the adjoint is *N*, distinctly not 1/2, which, again is the normalization of the "physics" structure constants. In math, they prefer to normalize the index of the adjoint to 1.

In any case, for  *SU(N)*,  you have 2 *N T*(fundamental)= *T*(adjoint), in all conventions, from the Kronecker product of a fundamental with an antifundamental.  Easily check everything with SU(2) which you probably know cold.

Comment: He said so in the comments.